# How to change mouse scroll speed using batch file in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, windows-7, mouse

I don't know which software did the trick, but my mouse scroll speed is constantly being changed to '1', after I set it to '3', maybe an hour later, it is reset to '1' again, which makes browsing code or webpages quite inconvenient.

I don't want to go to control panel → mouse too often. So how can I do it on the command line?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse" /v MouseSensitivity /t REG_SZ /d 20 /f
```

Just change the sensitivity as desired. 1 (lowest) - 20 (highest). Save as file `mouse.bat`, for example, and then put it in the startup folder in your start menu.

[Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/60668/how-do-i-persist-my-mouses-pointer-speed/60670#60670)

Comment: Uninstall your mouse drivers and reinstall a fresh copy.

Comment: And sometimes helps a hoover :)

Comment: Tried reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse" /v MouseSensitivity /t REG_SZ /d 5 /f   but didn't work. I guess MouseSensitivity isn't scrolling speed...

Comment: it works for me. maybe your mouse driver store it at another place, eg. an .INI file.

Answer (score 2):

[It was originally answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985682/how-do-i-change-mouse-settings-in-my-batch-script/55371778#55371778)

Changing registry values won't apply the changes.

The Windows system reads and loads them on startup, which doesn't happen on changing the values. You need to call system APIs to do that.

I've used a PowerShell script for same. You can find the code at

https://github.com/raevilman/windows-scripts/tree/master/mouse/speed

There I have placed two batch files. One for the touchpad and one for the USB mouse, because they both operate on different speeds. You will definitely have your version as per needs.

PS: Don't ask about PowerShell execution policy, etc., if you face them. Google it.

Comment: As @raevilman seems to have a phobia about answering simple questions on execution policy, to call a powershell script from a shortcut set the shortcut Target field to eg:

powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "[absolute path to ps1 script]"

Answer (score 0):

I found the wheel scroll setting under a different registry key. Try...

```
reg add "HKCU\\**Control Panel\Desktop**" /v **WheelScrollLines** /t REG_SZ /d 6 /f
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the BEST WAY to accomplish this task, and it will require NO intervention after you've completed the process once.

```
1. You must identify which MouseSensitivity registry entry is getting modified.  
   a) Start the registry editor in administrator mode.  
   b) Make sure you're at the first registry hive by clicking "Computer" at the top.  
   c) Press CTRL+F to open the Find dialogue, type "MouseSensitivity", and press ENTER.  
   d) Make note of the MouseSensitivity setting's value.  
   e) Change your mouse setting to anything other than the current setting.  
   f) Press F5 and see if the MouseSensitivity registry entry also changes.  
   g) If the setting changes, go to step number 2; If not, then continue to H.  
   h) Press F3 to search for the next MouseSensitivity entry and go back to step D.  

2. Now you want to lock in the desired setting and prevent it from being changed.  
   a) Change your mouse setting to your desired setting.  
   b) Press F5 and confirm that the MouseSensitivity registry entry also changes.  
   c) Now, with the setting highlighted, Open the Edit menu and select Permissions.  
   d) Select the Owner tab, click on your name, Check the option to "Replace  
      owner on subcontainers and objects", and slick on Apply.  
   e) Select the Permissions tab, uncheck "Include inheritable permissions from  
      this object's parent" and click Apply.  
   f) Under "Permission entries", select and Remove every entry.  
   g) Click on Add, in the "Enter the object name to select" box, type Everyone,  
      and click "Check Names". Verify "Everyone" gets underlined and click on OK.  
   h) Double click Everyone, and in the Permission Entry window, click Clear All.  
   i) Click these options under Allow:  
      Query Value; Enumerate Subkeys; Notify; Read Control  
   j) Click these options under Deny:  
      Set Value; Delete; Write DAC; Write Owner  
   k) Click OK to close the Permissions Entry window  
   l) Click OK to close the Advanced Security Settings window  
   m) Click OK to close the Permissions for Mouse window  
   n) Reboot the computer or log off and back on. (Not required but recommended)  

You should no longer have this problem, but keep in mind that if you ever want  
to change your mouse speed setting again, you'll have to do go back into the  
registry and restore write permissions to MouseSensitivity. Here's the easy way  
to do that (simplified instructions):  

   a) Open the permissions for MouseSensitivity.  
   b) Click Advanced to open the Advanced Security Settings for Mouse window.  
   c) Remove "Everyone" from the Permission entries list.  
   d) Check the "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent" box.  
   e) Click OK and OK to close both the Advanced window and Permissions window.  
   f) Reboot or log off and back on (Not required but recommended)
```

I hope this helps others in addition to the OP.