# How do I change mouse settings in my batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry

I'm trying to make a script that changes my mouse settings in the registry. When I run the script I see that the changes are made, but they won't be taken into effect unless I log out and log back in, which is not feasible.

```
:: MouseSensitivity                     10
:: MouseSpeed (Set Pointer Precision)   0
:: MouseThreshold1                      0
:: MouseThreshold2                      0

@ECHO OFF

REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse" /v MouseSensitivity /t REG_SZ /d 10 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse" /v MouseSpeed /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse" /v MouseThreshold1 /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse" /v MouseThreshold2 /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f

ECHO Execution logged on: %DATE% at %TIME% >> test.txt

:: /* Tried this, doesn't work.
:: RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
:: */

@EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: The registry is not an API. You need to call SystemParametersInfo from a language that can call Win32 APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Changing registry values won't apply the changes.

The Windows system reads and loads them on startup, which doesn't happen on changing the values. You need to call system APIs to do that.

I've used a PowerShell script for same. You can find the code at

https://github.com/raevilman/windows-scripts/tree/master/mouse/speed

There I have placed two batch files. One for the touchpad and one for the USB mouse, because they both operate on different speeds. You will definitely have your version as per needs.

PS: Don't ask about PowerShell execution policy, etc. If you face them, google it.

Answer (score 0):

Raymond Chen, you are right.
Here's the solution I came up with using C++.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    int mouse_info[3];

    mouse_info[0] = 0;  // MouseThreshold1
    mouse_info[1] = 0;  // MouseThreshold2
    mouse_info[2] = 0;  // Set Pointer Precision

    // Set and update user settings. In effect immediately.
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSE,
                         0,
                         mouse_info,
                         SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);

    return 0;
}
```